Angular config best practices
I'm developing an Angular frontend that calls a Spring Boot backend.
I know that I can store the API URL and other config options (like keycloak config or other api call config) in Angular environment files, but this isn't convenient for me.
With that configuration, I have to rebuild my frontend : which is really a shame.
Building the frontend takes time.
I don't want to build  my frontend for just config changes.
What is the best way to manage configuration by separating it from the source code?

The best option, IMO, is to use relative URLs, so you don't need to store the URL at all. You accomplish this by placing a reverse proxy in front of your containers. This way, you also get rid of any CORS problems.

I have an example in the answer to "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend.  (Though not specifically Angular.)
